# Hide content behind a preloading screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload, preloader

I have a preloading screen that I display on my site while the site's content loads. The issue I'm running into is that some of the content on the site will appear before the load screen goes away. Specifically, I have a page header and a button on the home page that slide in from the right and left. These sometimes slide in before the load screen goes away and the text of the two screens becomes jumbled. I want to make it so that even if the animations occur before the load screen goes away the user will not see the header and button that are there. Even better would be to make those animations not occur until the load screen disappears. I can set the animations to be delayed long enough for the pre load screen to disappear, but if the load screen goes away quickly there can be a pretty long latency before the animations occur.

Here is the code

HTML

```
<div id="load_screen" class="text-center">
 <div id="loading" class="text-center">
  <h3>Welcome to Jack Loud Photo!</h3>
  <p>Loading content...</p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x" aria-
  hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#load_screen {
 background: #000;
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1600px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div#load_screen > div#loading {
 color: #FFF;
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 300px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#loading > i.fa-spinner {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #28CC9E;
}
```

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
```

Comment: Here is a link to the site for reference http://jackloudphoto.com/

Comment: set z-index for #load_screen to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a `z-index` issue. You could see what elements have a higher `z-index` and make sure your `#load_screen`'s is higher.

But an easy way would be to wrap your page in an element (like `#page`) and set that to `opacity: 0` or `display: none`, and have `#load_screen` outside of that element so that everything on the page is hidden by default, and only `#load_screen` is visible.

Then on the window's `load` event, hide/remove `#load_screen` and toggle the `display` or `opacity` of `#page`. Aside from hiding everything but the loading screen, so that elements won't pop out and display over it, it also adds a neat UI/effect to the page.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
  document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
  document.getElementById('page').classList.add('ready');
});
```

```css
div#load_screen {
 background: #000;
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div#load_screen > div#loading {
 color: #FFF;
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 300px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#loading > i.fa-spinner {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #28CC9E;
}
#page {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
#page.ready {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/f/d/b/12917289761851255679earth-map-huge.jpg">
</div>
<div id="load_screen" class="text-center">
 <div id="loading" class="text-center">
  <h3>Welcome to Jack Loud Photo!</h3>
  <p>Loading content...</p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x" aria-
  hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```